# "I will write about stress" and why not "I will write about THE stress"

Tags: grammar

Why can't I use THE here?.And does it differ in meaning if I use THE?

Comment: What do you mean by _stress_? If **I** write about stress, I can write about stress in general, **or** about the stress on a particular syllable in a sentence. Like the word _or_ in the previous sentence.

Comment: This question is better suited to [English Language Learners.SE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Because you then need to explain what the specific stress it is you are taking about -

> - The stress of having small children
> - The stress of working as a flight controller".

Just stress is nonspecific stress

Answer (score 2):

There aren't really hard and fast rules in English for when `The` is used, there are only rationalizations.

My "rationalization" on this one would be that stress isn't exactly a sigular entity, like "the ball" or "the toaster" is.

However, sometimes "the" is used on stress. Particularly if its at the start of a sentence. For example, a person might say, "The stress is really getting to me". In that sentence, it would not really be correct (in AmE at least) to leave of the `The`.

But really, which words have a `the` in front of them isn't even consistent from dialect to dialect of English. You just have to memorize it.